# Regex get all english alphabetic characters in string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
متن آزمایشی Demo Text 4 1.0.5 – متن آزمایشی
```

I want to grab only the English text "Demo Text".

I used this regex `[a-zA-Z]` but it's only getting the first letter of the text.

Comment: You'd probably be better off replacing all non-alphabetical characters with empty strings. i.e. `regex replace ^[a-z] with ""`

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work for you:

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qY8dP5/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z ]+
```

try this

```
preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z ]+/sm', $text, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```